# « [...] a-t-il lancé dans un sourire » : pourquoi la préposition dans, sens ?

Tags: sens, prépositions, connotation

Un [article](http://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/grand-montreal/201711/10/01-5143141-un-navire-de-guerre-francais-a-montreal-pour-le-jour-du-souvenir.php) rapporte les propos du capitaine de la frégate de défense aérienne [*Forbin*](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forbin_(fr%C3%A9gate)), ayant accosté à Montréal (pour participer aux célébrations du [jour du Souvenir](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jour_du_Souvenir), après l'exercice Bold Alligator - [Fr](http://www.defense.gouv.fr/operations/operations/actualites/lancement-de-l-exercice-bold-alligator-2017), [US](http://www.public.navy.mil/usff/ba/Pages/default.aspx#partnerships), [UK](https://www.royalnavy.mod.uk/news-and-latest-activity/news/2017/october/27/171027-bold-moves-from-royal-marines-as-they-storm-beaches-in-us), [Can](http://forces.gc.ca/fr/archives-photos-recentes/2017/novembre.page) [etc.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bold_Alligator)), M. [Thomas Fraioli](http://www.colsbleus.fr/articles/9881), de la Marine nationale (République française), et commente :

> «Nous ne sommes pas du tout habitués à ce type de [température](http://www.lapresse.ca/actualites/environnement/201711/10/01-5143067-record-de-froid-historique-a-montreal.php?utm_categorieinterne=trafficdrivers&utm_contenuinterne=cyberpresse_les-plus-populaires-actualites_article_ECRAN1POS3), a-t-il
>   rappelé. Nous n'avons pas les habits nécessaires» pour affronter le
>   froid, a-t-il lancé **dans** un sourire.
>
> [ *La presse*, de La Presse Canadienne, 10 novembre 2017, je souligne ]

L'humour réchauffe. Au TLFi, on discute de l'adjonction de la préposition (avec, de, par, sans) avec [*sourire*](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/sourire/1), mais on ne mentionne pas l'emploi avec *dans*...

---

S'agit-il d'un sens distinct d'*avec un sourire* qui me serait inconnu ; qu'est-ce que ça voudrait dire/sous-entendre d'autre qu'à la (manière d'une) [blague](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/blague/1) ?

Comment: Je perçois la tournure comme une indication de la simultanéité de la parole et de l'apparition du sourire. Pas forcément un exemple typique ou une expression toute faite, mais pas du tout dissonant à mon oreille. →«Tu as des poils qui sortent de ton nez», m'a lancé ma jeune fille **dans** un bruyant éclat de rire qui m'a laissé très gêné dans ce restaurant tranquille.

Comment: I can't pin it down but I'm not sure, at least when used w/the forceful "lancer," that "dans un sourire" would even require a [visible] smile at all from the speaker (unlike "en souriant" or "avec un sourire" which would). "He added/threw in *jokingly*" wouldn't quite capture it in English 'cause I'm sure he wasn't joking at all about the brutal cold being something that needed to be confronted. Maybe "He threw in **playfully**" (either with or w/out a smile) would capture in English what I'm trying to express (="espièglement"?), or maybe even "in a deadpan manner" ("style pince-sans-rire"?).

Comment: @PapaPoule Thanks, interesting. The phrasal verb is such a beast in English, the preposition is within, so it becomes about how the adverb can add to it. Not sure but I sort of remember something like "in their teeth/beard" i.e. threw in (from) in their beard... usually when I reach a double preposition setup I've come to understand that I'm way way off idiomatic material. Anyways, insightful. As you know I'm a learner, but I dig your comparisons and questions. Most likely English plays a greater part in my mind than what I'd like to admit in terms of influence and syntax. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cette tournure nous indique selon moi que la réplique et le sourire étaient simultanés et liés : la réplique est amicale et décrit une situation qui malgré son inconfort demeure amusante, une anecdote qui se racontera avec plaisir plus tard à sa famille demeurée au loin, par-delà ces vastes plaines océaniques, et qui de ce fait mérite un sourire.

Ce n’est pas une tournure typique qui s’applique à toutes les situations de la vie, mais on relève ici et là quelques exemples similaires :

> L'ombre éteignit mes yeux, un cri vint à ma bouche
>   Et mon vieux coeur est mort **dans un frisson farouche.**
>         <sub>*–Bon chevalier masqué qui chevauche en silence*, Paul Verlaine</sub>
>    
>   La petite bossue devenait terrible, les yeux hagards et fixes, son corps difforme secoué de tremblements spasmodiqucs, et sa grande bouche appelant Jésus **dans une grimace hurlante et gémissante**.
>         <sub>*–L’évangéliste*, Alphonse Daudet</sub>

La question m’a aussi rappelé une embarassante situation que j’ai vécue il y a quelques années dans un restaurant tranquille où une dizaine de clients déjeunaient calmement. Les curieux en trouveront la description en commentaire à la question, ci-dessus. J’en ai cherché un exemple plus ancien et plus littéraire... Voici donc une réplique signée Paul Féval :

> — Qui vous a dit cela, monsieur le matador? s’écria Gonzague **dans un éclat de rire** qui sonna faux.

De l’éclat de rire au sourire, il n’y a que l’atténuation du mouvement et de l’interférence sonore, ce qui ne peut finalement qu’aider à la compréhension du message.

L’exemple de la question originale est probablement le contexte le plus évident pour utiliser *« dans un sourire »*. La littérature et la poésie ont fourni d’autres exemples, plus complexes et très beaux :

> Et quand je croyais voir le ciel dans ses yeux d'ange,
>   Un mot tombé soudain **dans un sourire étrange**
>   Soufflait sur mon beau rêve, et mon cœur restait seul
>         <sub>*–Le départ*, Adolphe Carcassonne</sub>
>    
>   — Comment vous trouvez-vous ? acheva la paysanne. — Tout prêt à recommencer, si votre service l'exige, répondit-il.
>
> La paysanne lui envoya un remerciement **dans un sourire.**
>         <sub>*–Les Louves de Machecoul*, Alexandre Dumas</sub>

---

#### Quelques pas dans l’abstraction

Un sourire, un frisson, une grimace, un éclat de rire, ça demeure concret. Repensant à tout ceci, je me suis dis qu’il serait sans doute possible de suivre cette tournure dans des régions moins substantielles, de trouver des cas où ce qui accompagne un fait avéré (une parole, une crise d’épilepsie, l’arrivée de la mort) est plus difficile à discerner objectivement, à mesurer absolument. Voici quelques exemples que j’ai pu glaner.

***Dans un élan de prophétique enthousiasme***

> Et qui sait? dit Yvernès, **dans un élan** de prophétique enthousiasme, qui sait si le continent, qui fut englouti sous les eaux du Pacifique, ne reparaîtra pas un jour à sa surface, reconstruit par ces myriades d’animalcules microscopiques?
>         <sub>*–L’île à hélice*, Jules Verne</sub>

***Dans une volonté contraire***

> Le visage de Nitchef exprimait une tension de volonté impérieuse et violente. Des gouttes de sueur découlaient de son front.
>   « Nadia ! répéta le nihiliste d’une voix sourde.
>   — Non ! non ! gronda Mohr raidi, lui aussi, **dans une volonté** contraire. Je ne veux pas !
>   — Nadia !
>   — Non ! »
>         <sub>*–La bombe silencieuse*, Charles Dodeman</sub>

***Dans un sursaut d’exaspération***

> Il pénétra, **dans un sursaut d’exaspération,** tout ce qu’il ne voulait pas savoir et tout ce qu’on n’osait point lui dire.
>         <sub>*–Fort comme la mort*, Guy de Maupassant</sub>

---

#### Pourquoi pas *« [...] a-t-il lancé avec un/le sourire »*

La tournure *« avec un sourire »* est très possible. Pourquoi ne fut-elle pas privilégiée ?

Dans ma vision de la chose, *« dans un sourire »* est plus chaleureux. Plus détendu aussi. Une remarque dite *« avec un sourire »* me fait penser à l’arrivée d’un couple dans une soirée: la parole est accompagnée d’un sourire, mais la parole et le sourire sont des entités indépendantes, liées momentanément par les circonstances. Par contre, une remarque dite *« dans un sourire »* est transportée par le sourire *(voire à l’intérieur du sourire, selon* [jcm69](https://french.stackexchange.com/users/13816) *qui en fit la remarque dans un commentaire ci-dessous)*, les deux nous arrivent ensemble comme un tout indivisible, le message existe à travers le sourire, le sourire à cause du message.

La différence est subtile, et mon évaluation de la syntaxe n’est sans doute pas absolue, c’est pourquoi il est possible que je sois naïf de penser que ce fut prémédité de la part de l’auteur, mais en même temps, comme il a fait un choix que j’approuve, je me dis que je ne suis pas forcément complètement dans le faux.

Comment: Un peu comme _en_ finalement. Merci !

Comment: @Galèrefranquiste Je me suis aperçu d'un aspect de votre question négligé dans ma réponse... Un contraste entre *«avec un sourire»* et *«dans un sourire»*? Ma vision: dans le premier cas, la réplique  arrive accompagnée d'un sourire (ils viennent bras dessus bras dessous); dans le second, la réplique arrive transportée par un sourire (le sourire est jugé aussi important que les mots prononcés, il est partie intégrante du message). Jugez-vous cette interprétation plausible?

Comment: Dans le deuxième cas, la réplique est même transportée *dans* plutôt que *par* le sourire. Le sourire pourrait donc être plus important que les mots prononcés: on reçoit d'abord le sourire puis le message contenu. Peut-être.

Comment: Oui, c'est plausible. Mon approche est souvent purement lexicale. Je lis un truc et je trouve ça inusité, je vais au TLFi et je ne trouve pas le syntagme, je ne sais jamais si c'est du à mon ignorance ou c'est simplement quelque chose d'inhabituel mais bien senti. Ici je comprenais évidemment mais j'étais curieux de comprendre pourquoi on faisait ce choix, et même si souvent j'ai une et même plusieurs hypothèses, j'aime savoir ce que d'autres personnes avec des horizons différents, comme les vôtre ou ceux des gens des vieux pays, en pensent. N'hésitez pas à ajouter à votre réponse. Merci !

Comment: Merci pour les ajouts et les exemples ! Quand on lit les exemples, on s'habitue pour ainsi dire. J'ai l'impression que _avec un sourire_ est simplement plus figé donc plus proche du réflexe et donc ne pas le voir m'a surpris. Moi aussi c'est un choix que je peux approuver, et qui demande simplement plus de réflexion que le réflexe ou syntagme typique. La nuance est ce que j'aime de ma langue et donc pourquoi s'en passer !